# Dissipative Hamiltonian System with a Periodic Force

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $H:P \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Hamiltonian on a symplectic manifold $(\omega,P)$ and let $X_H: P \to TP$ be the Hamiltonian vector-field.  Let $F:P \to T^*P$ be a dissipative force field such that for $Y = \omega^{\sharp}(F)$ we have that $Y[H] < 0$ everywhere outside a point $x_0 \in P$.  This makes $x_0$ a stable point of the dissipative Hamiltonian system $(P,\omega,H,F)$.  Now let $f: \mathbb{R} \times P \to T^*P$ be a time-periodic force.  My question:  Does there exists a periodic orbit (near $x_0$) for the periodically forced system $(P,\omega,H, F + \epsilon f)$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ ?  I'm sure the answer is yes, but how big can $\epsilon$ be?

Comment: Can you provide a reference explaining what's a "dissipative Hamiltonian system"?

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with all your notation, but I assume $Y$ is the vector field corresponding to $F$ and $Y[H]$ the derivative of $H$ with respect to $Y$ that indicates dissipativeness.

First of all, is there a reason that the fixed point $x_0$ is stable instead of unstable?

Secondly, I would look at the linearized system around $x_0$. If the eigenvalues are strictly negative, then the fixed point must persist. This can be extended to time-periodic or generally time-dependent perturbations. To estimate the size of $\epsilon$, you need to look at the proof of the stable manifold thm.

Comment: Thankyou Jaap.  I will take a look.  Your interpretation of the notation is correct.  Secondly, I guess you are right.  There is no reason to discriminate the unstable case.  For dissipative systems I'd expect to find a stable periodic orbit from a stable point.  Under time-reversal a stable equilibria would become an unstable one, and the corresponding stable limit cycle would become unstable as well.